# Invoice model recommendation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I just started to develop an invoice app. I would like to hear your opinions and recommendations about this dilemma.

The invoice has a client section. The client can be selected from a drop-down select menu or it can be entered directly into a text field. Let's say it's just a one time purchase and the client won't ever come back. Should I have these two columns: client_id and client_field so either of those two can be filled out? The negative side is that a lot of client_field will be empty. Or should I not use a client_field and just add a new client even thought that client will only be used once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be consistent and use a separate client model and `client_id` even for clients that only appear once. If you have both `client_id` and `client_model` you will have extra complexity:

- Your validation will have to check both and ensure that everything is consistent.
- You will have to `o.client.try(:name) || o.client_field` and such all over the place just to display data.
- If you change the structure of your client records in the future you will have to reformat your "table within a table" `client_field` kludge.
- Any database based reporting will go from simple SQL to a monstrosity of LEFT JOINs and CASE statements.

And those are just a couple things off the top of my head.

If you're worried about having a dropdown with a lot of entries — and you should be worried about any dropdown with more than ~20 entries — then go with just an autocompleting text input or limit the dropdown to the top ~20 clients and use a autocompleting text input for the rest (or perhaps even a JavaScript based combo-box); there's a good chance that the dropdown won't even get used by your users, accountants and other people that do a lot of data entry and invoicing often hate having to reach for the mouse.

Comment: The client can be a person or the client can be an organization. Should I separate the models? Or make a model association? For example: client belongs_to organizations (or companies)

Comment: @leonel: Depends on how different they are. You could just have clients to start and maybe an "is a company" flag.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with having an auto-complete field where, if submitted without a matching ID, you will just create the client and link them in?

That's what's expected from the stand-point of the user and it's how applications like QuickBooks have worked for years.

Comment: Yes, but let's say the client it's not a recurring client, it's just a one time purchase and the client never ever comes back again. Now let's say there are hundreds or thousands or clients like this. There will be a lot of unused clients in the client list.

Comment: It's a big presumption that they will never, ever come back. What is the cost of storage versus the convenience of having a client's name already entered on the off chance that they return? Probably marginal. You can always have a flag in your customer list with something like `repeat` to indicate they have done business more than once for reporting purposes, etc.